# Programa em Java que vem com JRE

Tags: java

Quero criar um programa em Java, mas que a pessoa não precise ter o Java instalado no computador dela. Tem como eu colocar uma JRE junto do meu programa com apenas as classes necessárias?

Um exemplo:
Eu criei um programa e só usei a classe System e as classes que System chama. Não tem como eu fazer um JRE com apenas as classes que estão sendo usadas?

Fora isso, o que eu mais preciso é que eu tenha a JRE junta do programa, e quando eu colocar o programa no pc da pessoa, ele instala a JRE (compactada ou não) e o programa consegue rodar

Conseguiu entender? Se não, me avise.

Comment: Igor, pelo que entendi o que você deveria fazer é criar um instalar personalizado que iria instalar/atualizar o java além de instalar seu software. Procure por softwares criados de instalação que isso pode resolver seu problema

Comment: Se usar JavaFX é exatamente o que ocorre quando usar o [Native Packaging](https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/native_packaging_for_javafx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode adicionar o JRE (ou JDK dependendo da sua aplicação) ao diretório de instalação do seu programa. Para isso, baixe o JRE em formato compactado (tar.gz) e descompacte em um diretório dentro do diretório de instalação do seu programa. Quando for executar o seu programa, utilize o executável do Java que está nesse novo diretório.

**Exemplo:**

Supondo que você queira usar o JRE 1.7 em um ambiente windows 7 de 64bits, voce deveria fazer o download [nesse link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1880261.html) do arquivo jre-7u67-windows-x64.tar.gz.
Se o seu programa usar a estrutura abaixo:

[image: pacote]

bastaria descompactar o JRE em um diretório, por exemplo jre_interno.
Depois é só editar o arquivo bat para usar o novo JRE.

**Importante**

Como não foi instalado, esse JRE em específico não será atualizado automaticamente (a não ser que você também faça isso) podendo comprometer a segurança do ambiente.

Comment: Muito bom. Só mais uma coisa: o código do bat seria pra executar o arquivo java.exe? Tipo: jre/.../java Programa.class

Comment: @IgorCostaMelo exatamente.