# Menor JRE(jvm) possível

Tags: java

Eu estou criando um aplicativo Java e preciso por a JRE junto, e algum wrapper, ou mesmo um instalador. Existe algum programa que faça isso, com a MENOR jre possível já incluso?

Comment: Sobre colocar o JRE junto, aqui tem uma resposta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30154/ - Falta alguém falar como criar o menor pacote possível que rode a aplicação.

Comment: Eu estava tentando um modo de por tudo dentro de um .exe, mas acaba que fica gigantesco

Comment: Esse é um problema bem comum. O pessoal empacota o JRE inteiro. Seria legal se alguém conseguisse uma resposta com uma solução sensata pra montar um "JRE lite" só com o que a aplicação precisa de fato.

Comment: Muito difícil fazer isso. O principal arquivo é o rt.jar e ele pesa 50MB na JRE7. Dá pra se livrar de alguns .exe's e .jar's desnecessários para a aplicação, mas chuto que não dá pra salvar mais que 50MB do tamanho do total da JRE seja lá qual estiver usando.

Comment: É muito triste eu ter uma aplicação de 2MB e ela ficar com 60~70MB

Comment: Seria melhor usar outra linguagem. Ou pode tentar a sorte usando uma solução como esta: http://www.excelsiorjet.com

Comment: Eu conheço o Excelsior Jet , e , ele também tem o mesmo problema, embora seja um pouco menor