# Preciso baixar a JVM para rodar um programa java no meu PC uma vez que não sou desenvolvedor?

Tags: java, jvm, jdk

Preciso baixar a JVM para rodar um programa java no meu PC uma vez que não sou desenvolvedor, ou seja, só irei precisar da JVM, apenas para rodar esse programa? Melhor, como os programas feitos em java rodam nas máquinas das pessoas sem que elas baixem a JVM, nem sequer sabem o que é isso? Agradeço muito quem me responder, vivo com essa questão na cabeça. :(

Comment: jvm é o java jre que voce instala no navegador(ou instalava antigamente). Só entrar no site da oracle e instalar, qual a dificuldade?

Comment: https://www.java.com/pt_BR/

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30154/programa-em-java-que-vem-com-jre

Answer (score 4):

> Preciso baixar a JVM para rodar um programa java no meu PC uma vez que não sou desenvolvedor, ou seja, só irei precisar da JVM, apenas para rodar esse programa?

Sim.

> Melhor, como os programas feitos em java rodam nas máquinas das pessoas sem que elas baixem a JVM, nem sequer sabem o que é isso?

Para a maioria dos programas em Java, sim, você tem que baixar a JVM.

Há dois casos que fogem disso:

- Alguns programas executáveis em Java já têm dentro deles uma JVM embutida.
- Alguns programas instalam a JVM como parte do seu processo de instalação.

Comment: Muito boa sua resposta, vlw!